# Restar valor y conocer tipo de resultado (positivo/negativo)

Tags: mysql

Tengo una query que me realiza una resta entre dos valores.

Me gustaría añadirle mas información a la consulta para que me indique si el resultado ha incrementado o disminuido (por ejemplo: "sube precio" , "baja precio"

```
select ROUND((price_old - price_new),2) AS PRECIO, description from Product_Update;
+--------+-------------------------------------+
| PRECIO | description                         |
+--------+-------------------------------------+
|   3.99 | producto 1                          |
|  12.99 | producto 2                          |
|     -1 | producto 2                          |
+--------+-------------------------------------+
```

como adapto la consulta para que me añada una nueva columna?

```
+--------+-------------------------------------+
| PRECIO | Estado      | description           |
+--------+-------------------------------------+
|   3.99 | sube precio | producto 1            |
|  12.99 | sube precio | producto 2            |
|     -1 | baja precio | producto 3            |
+--------+-------------------------------------+
```

gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es un `CASE WHEN` asi:

```
select ROUND((price_old - price_new),2) AS PRECIO,
  CASE
    WHEN ROUND((price_old - price_new),2) > 0 THEN "Precio sube"
    WHEN ROUND((price_old - price_new),2) = 0 THEN "Iguanas"
    ELSE "Precio baja"        
  END as estado,
  description 
from Product_Update;
```

Comment: genial gracias!